# Post Multiple images by statuses/update_with_media twitter api of abraham's twitteroauth library

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to post multiple images by statuses/update_with_media twitter api of abraham's twitteroauth library.
    I am posting single image but not multiple images.

```
My code is like below:

$params = array('media[]' => file_get_contents($image_url),
                'status' => $message
               );
$connection->post('statuses/update_with_media',$params,true);

Where $connection is a object of TwitterOAuth.

Function of TwitterOAuth library is below:

function post($url, $parameters = array(), $multipart = false) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'POST', $parameters, $multipart);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

I know I have to do some change in media[].But I can not get proper output.
So please suggest me.

Thanks in advance
Harry Shah

Answer (score 0):

You can post multiple images on twitter like this

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, 
   $access_token_secret);
$firstimage = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => '/path/to/file/kabootar1.jpg']);
$secondimage = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => '/path/to/file/kabootar2.jpg']);
$parameters = [
'status' => 'This is a test tweet',
'media_ids' => implode(',', [$firstimage->media_id_string, $secondimage->media_id_string])];
 $output = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```